# Where is the node_modules directory located in a React Native project?

Tags: react-native, npm

In a simple JavaScript application that utilizes npm modules, I have a package.json, and after running `npm install` I get a node_modules folder.

How does this work in React Native, where is the node_modules directory in a React Native project?

Comment: It should be on the same level as your `package.json`

Comment: True, it is, I noticed that it is in fact there when I `ls` from the command line. However, I can't see it in my editor, Atom, which is strange because in normal projects I always see it. Any idea why this is so?

Comment: Maybe this [issue](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/3429) provides an explanation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The location should be in the root of your project. Assume your root project directory on `AwesomeProject` it should be on `AwesomeProject/node_modules`.

How do you create your react native app ? If you using `create-react-native-app` it will automatically install the npm packages.

```
create-react-native-app AwesomeProject
cd AwesomeProject
npm start
```

If not, try run `npm install` on your root project (contain package.json).

Comment: I create my app using `react-native init`, then I `npm install`. You know what, I just noticed that I can't see node_modules in Atom for React Native projects, but it is in fact there in my root directory when I check on the command line. I only looked at Atom because for normal projects I don't have this issue, node_modules is simply visible there.

Comment: i see, maybe you can try modify your atom editor's settings. `Settings > Packages > Core Packages`. and set “Hide Ignored Names” and “Hide VCS Ignored Files”. full reference http://blog.lukebennett.com/2015/09/21/show-hidden-files-in-atom-sidebar/

Answer (score 2):

npm install

you will see node_modules in the root of your project;

Answer (score 2):

As you said you can see the module in when you do ls in terminal. That means that "node_module" is in .gitignore. Atom excludes files which are gitignored. You can disable that settings.
Following are the steps for mac.
Go to atom preferences > Core > and untick "Exclude VCS Ignored Path" option.

There will be similar settings in windows also if you are developing in windows